# OnTouchListener does not translate during TranslationAnimation

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

I have a problem with an ImageView that moves on the screen. Unfortunately, the `onTouch Event` is only fired when I touch the original location of the ImageView. When the `imageView` is moving, it is ignoring the onTouch Event. In summary, the original position is the only way to trigger the OnTouch event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Property Animations instead of these View Animations. Handle the touch is one of the most important reasons to use this kind of animations.

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", 0f, 100f);
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.start();
```

If you want further information follow this link: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Comment: I love you, buddy. Right now, It is working perfectly. Only thing, I changed in my code it was this line
 TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, -100.0f);
to:  
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myImageView, "translationY", 0f, -100f);

Comment: I was looking for a solution for days and only thing I realized that the Translate Animation does not do anything with the actual location of the view.